# Dozer mapping not working for nested object

Tags: java, spring-mvc, nhibernate, dozer

I was Trying to copy value of `StudentRequestForm` class  to `StudentEntity` class .all values are saved but a `classI` field in `studentBean` is not saved which is mapped to  `StudentEntity` `classId` .So i want my ClassI value copy to classId

you can check in below dozer mapping

---

```
public class StudentRequestForm {

        private StudentModel studentbean;

        public StudentModel getStudentbean() {
            return studentbean;
        }
        public void setStudentbean(StudentModel studentbean) {
            this.studentbean = studentbean;
        }`enter code here`




public class StudentModel {

    private int countryId,cityId,stateId,classI;
    private String enrollmentId,firstName,lastName,gender,category,pincode,sectionName;



@Entity
@Table(name="students")
public class StudentEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private int age;

    private String category;

    private String pincode;

    private int cityId;

    @Column(name="class_id")
    private int classId;

    @Column(name="country_id")
    private int countryId;



        @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    private String gender
```

...................
................
;

Dozer mapping

```
<mapping>
    <class-a>com.myschool.entity.StudentRequestForm</class-a>
    <class-b>com.myschool.entity.StudentEntity</class-b>

    <field>
         <a>studentbean.classI</a>   
        <b>classId</b>
    </field>


</mapping>
```

controller methood

```
public ModelAndView saveForm(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response,StudentRequestForm studentForm){
        try{


        StudentEntity studententity = mapper.map(studentForm.getStudentbean(), StudentEntity.class);
        studentservice.saveStudentForm(studententity);

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return new ModelAndView("abc/helo.html");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `StudentModel` class to Dozer, but in your mapping, you are using `StudentRequestForm`. 
So, either do this

```
StudentEntity studententity = mapper.map(studentForm, StudentEntity.class);
```

OR

```
    <class-a>com.myschool.entity.StudentModel</class-a>
    <class-b>com.myschool.entity.StudentEntity</class-b>

    <field>
         <a>classI</a>   
        <b>classId</b>
    </field>
```